# Xamarin Forms : Adjust listview rowheight based on a condition

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to adjust the row height of a listview based on a condition?
My Condition: If the value of **{Binding isMediaUrlNull}** is true set the height as 250 else 500.
Either in xaml or in class I need to add this condition. For avoiding the blank space between the items I am applying this.

Please suggest a solution for this  :) 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to set the HeightRequest of the Grid that is the parent control in the data template to one of your 2 heights based on a binding condition.

EDIT

Just spun up a quick app to check and yes you can bind the HeightRequest of the parent grid to a Model property.

Make sure you set the HasUnevenRows property of the ListView to True.

Comment: Now I add HasUnevenRows="True" to listview, then it solves the unwanted space between items. But I have a boxview on the lefthandside. I also need to set the height of that based on the content height. I added picture to my question now.